# can not delete products in magento admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using magento 1.9.2 ,In that When i am trying to delete products it will show error like below

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'mageproductid ' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT main_table.* FROM marketplace_product AS main_table WHERE (mageproductid = '208')

Comment: it seems that you are using some custom module, have you tried this sql directly from PHPmyadmin.

Comment: It seems like you are using an extension by marketplace. Disable this extension and try to delete the product.

Comment: Arushi In this marketplace_product  table  product id is not saving

Comment: I think you are using some extension,Better to take advice from them.while you are installing the extension may be the sql scripts are not run properly

Comment: try disable the extension and try to delete.....